# Convert mysql subquery + group by to laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got this MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   `album_picture_category` r 
        WHERE  r.`category_id` = b.`category_id` 
        GROUP  BY r.`category_id`) AS count 
FROM   `album_picture_category` b 
GROUP  BY( `category_id` );
```

that I want to convert to Laravel Eloquent, I tried:

```php
PictureAlbumCategory::addSelect([

'count' => function ($query) { $query->select('count(*)')->from('album_picture_category r')->whereColumn('r.category_id', 'album_picture_category.category_id')->groupBy('r.category_id'); 

}])->groupBy('category_id')
->get();
```

but it does not work; I get

> PHP Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:/xampp/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php on line 58

Anyone got hints on what I did wrong?

Result should look like this:

```
album_id  |  category_id  |  count  |
    1           1               1
    1           2               1
    1           3               1
    1           5               1
    1           6               1
    1           7               1
    1           9               1
    2           13              1
    1           14              2
    1           15              2
    1           16              2
    1           17              2
```

2 pivot table rows + count column which is the occurrence count

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? .. you expect something to happen but something else happens, we need to know what you expect and what actually happens

Comment: can you use raw query? just asking

Comment: @lagbox hi, I am getting `PHP Warning:  strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:/xampp/htdocs/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php on line 58`

Comment: @Danyal Sandeelo hi, is it possible to make it work without Raw Query? if not then maybe

Comment: where did you see `addSelect` used that way?

Comment: Laravel has a `withCount()` method, so all you need to do is define your relationship properly and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in  laravel but i suggest for an easy conversion (and right scoping and  better peformance) instead of a subquery for column  you could try using the subquery in JOIN

```
SELECT *, t.count_category
FROM   `album_picture_category` b 
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT Count(*) count_category
        FROM    r.`category_id`, `album_picture_category` r 
        GROUP  BY r.`category_id`
) t ON t.category_id = b.category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `selectRaw` and `groupBy`. you can try this code. i hope this code help you.

```
PictureAlbumCategory::groupBy('category_id')
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as total, category_id')
        ->get();
```